# Control the order in which customization options appear?

Tags: elisp

In my major mode, I have some options defined with `defcustom` and `defface`. Each is assigned to the same `:group` defined via `defgroup`.

When I do `M-x customize-mode`, the options all appear and work correctly.

However I don't like the *order* in which they appear. For example I'd like to put at the top customizations users are more likely to need or want to change.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how Emacs determines the order. For example it doesn't seem to correspond to the order in which they are defined in the `.el` file, or an alphabetical sort of their doc strings or `:tag`s. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but it seems to be... "random"? In reading Elisp docs and searching online I haven't found an answer.

Is it possible to control the order in which the options appear, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of options is determined by <kbd>C-h a custom.*(sort\|order) RET</kbd>:

```
custom-browse-order-groups
  User option: If non-nil, order group members within each
               customization group.
  Properties: standard-value custom-type custom-requests
              variable-documentation
custom-browse-sort-alphabetically
  User option: If non-nil, sort customization group alphabetically in
               `custom-browse'.
  Properties: variable-documentation custom-autoload custom-loads
              standard-value custom-type custom-requests
custom-buffer-order-groups
  User option: If non-nil, order group members within each
               customization group.
  Properties: standard-value custom-type custom-requests
              variable-documentation
custom-buffer-sort-alphabetically
  User option: Whether to sort customization groups alphabetically in
               Custom buffer.
  Properties: variable-documentation custom-autoload custom-loads
              standard-value custom-type custom-version
              custom-requests
custom-menu-order-groups
  User option: If non-nil, order group members within each
               customization group.
  Properties: standard-value custom-type custom-requests
              variable-documentation
custom-menu-sort-alphabetically
  User option: If non-nil, sort each customization group
               alphabetically in menus.
  Properties: variable-documentation custom-autoload custom-loads
              standard-value custom-type custom-requests
```

and implemented by `custom-sort-items`.

I.e., they can be sorted alphabetically and groups can be placed first or last.

If you want to add custom sorting, you will need to modify the source or use [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Comment: So to make sure, I think you're saying that the ordering of options is shared by all customization groups, and normally something that the user specifies. Therefore if I wanted to change it for my mode's customization group, I would need to `defadvice` the `customize-mode` function, and temporarily change the ordering. Is that (roughly) correct?

Comment: More or less; you would probably want to advise `custom-sort-items` - but I suggest modifying the sources to accept user sorting function and submitting the patch upstream.